# Chakra UI not changing to dark mode in Next.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I recently tried to integrate Chakra UI into my Next.js app. I have followed every step in the guide in their docs: https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started/nextjs-guide

However, when I set the initialColorMode to "dark" for the ColorModeScript prop, it does not apply. In fact, when I check the elements in chrome dev tools, my body tag still shows it has the class "chakra-ui-light" and the html tag has the data-theme as light and style="color-scheme: light".

I am not sure why this is the case. Anyone able to help? Here is the code related to my attempt at forcing dark mode:

```
const config = {
  initialColorMode: "dark",
  useSystemColorMode: false,
};

const theme = extendTheme({ config });
```

Then I wrap in _app.js with:
`<ChakraProvider theme={theme}>`

document.js like this:

```
<body>
    <ColorModeScript initialColorMode="dark" />
    <Main />
    <NextScript />
</body>
```

Edit: I found today that this bug is actually happening in development environment only. When I deploy to Vercel, it does indeed have color mode set to dark. I am still not sure why this is the case.

Comment: The docs say to use `<ColorModeScript initialColorMode={theme.config.initialColorMode} />` not `<ColorModeScript initialColorMode="dark" />`?

Comment: I have tried both @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had a similar problem and my solution was to remove "chakra-ui-color-mode" from localstorage and refresh the page.

Comment: Thank you so much . This is the answer that worked for me. I was continuously changing the codes and nothing was working.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cookies it will work. :)

Comment: your answer is unclear please provide some details how to clean cookies or at least why